# Match Self-Recursive Type in Macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

I guess self-recursive types are well-known in Scala. A nice intro can be found at [here](https://www.alessandrolacava.com/blog/scala-self-recursive-types/). The following piece of code is taken from that page:

```
trait Doubler[T <: Doubler[T]] { self: T =>
  def double: T
}
```

In Scala 3 Macros, we can match on types, introduced with examples on [this page](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/macros/quotes.html) (right before "Quote types patterns" Section). However, I still don't know how to match self-recursive types. **Any idea?**

Imagine that I have the following method:

```
def doSomething[T <: Doubler[T]](value: T): Unit = { ... }
```

And the following macro:

```
  inline def myMacro[A](inline value: A): Unit = ${ myMacroImpl('value) }

  private def myMacroImpl[A: Type](value: Expr[A])(using q: Quotes): Expr[Unit] =
    import q.reflect.*
    value match
      case '{ $x: /*help-me*/ } => '{ doSomething($x) }
      case _ => // irrelevant
```

How should I fix the first case to make the code even compile?

Comment: Maybe `case '{ $x: Doubler[A] } ` ? I admit it's a guess..

Comment: @GaëlJ That gives the usual error: `Type argument A does not conform to upper bound Doubler[LazyRef(A)]`

Comment: Could you maybe do `erasedValue[A] match { case _: Doubler[t] => ...  }`?